# How to add web folder to chef's private nginx?

Tags: nginx, chef-infra

In my Chef recipes I use **remote_file** to access files at http server. I would like to use Chef server's ngnix to serve those files.
How to configure Chef's nginx to serve files in specific folder using http?

Comment: That's a very bad idea. 1) This is not a supported feature. 2) It will break at any update if you persist and tweak it. 3) Use a real artifact manager like nexus or artifactory OR use a standalone nginx/apache to provide those packages, you'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have many machines in LAN to be configured with Chef. There are also many **remote_file** resources in our recipes. The problem was: downloading from internet takes a lot of time, but at the same time the file was available on another machine in LAN.

What I did is:

- Installed Nexus for binary file storage.
- Monkeypatched **remote_file** resource using a library in a cookbook, so that it gets loaded every time a cookbook is loaded overwriting original resource behaviour.

Now every time **remote_file** resource has to download some file, it will first ask Nexus. If that file is available in Nexus, it downloads from there.
If there is no such file there, Chef downloads the file from original source and then uploads it to Nexus too for other nodes.

Comment: I did not want to install one more software. Maintenance, documentation,... I was hopping to get single entry in existing/new config file.

Comment: Sounds somewhat complex to me. Setting up just an nginx instance shouldn't be that much hassle, right? If VMs are expensive to you, let it run on the same node as the Chef Server, but a second nginx instance on another port. Don't fiddle with Chef Server setup itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a feature of Chef. You can use the `files/` folder in a cookbook and the `cookbook_file` resource to serve files directly from the Chef Server but it is very limited and you should really use your own server to manage large files or complex downloads.